# How to Design a T filp flop using only basic logic gates

Tags: circuit-design, flipflop, logic-gates

I know how to design combinational circuits(ex Binary code to bcd code)
1) Draw truth table
2) Draw K - map, derive Boolean funcntion
3) Design circuits from boolean fucntion

but I don't know How to design a T flip-flop. 
How can I derive truth-table for desiging t flip-flop 
What truth table? What inputs? What k maps? What steps?

I should design this using only basic logic gates
Could you explain it easily?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no prior research such as [this google page](https://www.google.com/search?q=T+flip-flop&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimvdu8j9PbAhXLBsAKHR8nAnsQ_AUICigB&biw=1249&bih=902)

Comment: I dont like this question since a half-hearted google search provides many resources to answer this. It is clear that the OP did not put any time into trying to figure it out.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.
I don't just want to follow the circuit ; I want to find a step-by-step way to design it.  
Most of the information on Google is only explaining with a complete flip-flop

Comment: In that case, the question is far too broad. General instructions on the construction of *asynchronous state machines* is the topic of entire college courses and books, much more than we can address in the Q&A format used here.

Answer (score 2):

The concept needed to describe a flip flop appears to be missing.  The output of such devices change with time.  Consequently using a static truth table will be a challenge.  Instead, use a [state transition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table).

When constructing such devices it is important to consider how the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) is used to drive change over time.

Lastly, when ever possible, build upon simpler designs.  An *R S Flip Flop* can be used in the creation of a *J K Flip Flop*.  And a *J K Flip Flop* can be used in the creation of a *T Flip Flop*.

Comment: Notice I did not so much as tell you the solution then tell you how to think about the solution.  I remember having this conundrum back in college & this was the key to understanding how flip flops worked.